# Magento 2 how to override the special price

Tags: magento2, price

all can you help me how to override a product's special price? I want to unset Special Price if that product does not meet my condition.

I was able to override Price to my custom value, but if there is any special price exists for that product, then the special price is showing so I can't set my custom price for that product.

Comment: I would save a special price on `product save after event`.

Comment: I can't update price value to table for that product, my condition will work daily basis.

Comment: Then have cron job to save price for the products matching your condition.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty late but still, incase someone need this. You can achieve this by plugin. Create a new module and create `di.xml` with below content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
   <plugin name="change_product" type="vendor\module\Plugin\Model\Product" sortOrder="1" />
 </type>
</config>
```

and the plugin at this location `vendor_module/Plugin/Model/Product.php` with the content:

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Plugin\Model;

class Product
{

 public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
 { 

   return $result +100;
  }

  public function afterGetSpecialPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
  { 
   return $result +100;
  }
}
```

this will change the regular price and the special price. Write the same for the tier price.

don't forget to run `setup:upgrade` command and `cache:clean`
Good day :)

Answer (score 1):

First Create ‘Module.xml’ file at below location using following code. It will help to override our custom layout file. Path: `app\code\OSCP\ModuleName\etc\module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="OSCP_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
            <module name="Magento_CatalogWidget"/>
            <module name="Magento_Widget"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Now it’s time to create our own custom layout at following path using this code. Path: `app\code\OSCP\ModuleName\view\base\layout\catalog_product_prices.xml`

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
                <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">OSCP_ModuleName::catalog/product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</layout>
```

Lastly, we have to create one more file ‘default.phtml’ with our logic of overriding default price. Path: `app\code\OSCP\ModuleName\view\base\templates\catalog\product\price\amount\default.phtml`

```
<?php
$objectManagerIn = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$priceArr = explode('-', $block->getPriceId());
foreach ($priceArr as $item)
{
    if(is_numeric($item)){
        $pid=$item;
        break;
    }
}
$product = $objectManagerIn->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()->load($pid);
$priceHelper = $objectManagerIn->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); ?>
<span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
    <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
<?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
    <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
    <?php $ finalprice =$product->getFinalPrice();
        $finalprice+=(($finalprice*15)/100); ?>
    <span class="price-label">
<h4>    <b><?php echo $priceHelper->currency($finalprice, true, false);  ?></b>
</h4>
</span>
</span>
```

You can change **$finalprice** as per your requirement of price. Also, you can manipulate with these codes according to your needs.